# How can I run Vim on the same txt Window on Win x64?

Tags: windows, vim

Every time I run Vim from the command line of poweshell or cmd, it start another Window.

When on Windows via ssh in txt mode, Vim will also start a new window on the screen. Fine!

Does anybody know if there is a command line switch, a variable or other things that Vim is running in the same txt window where it is started?

Comment: `vim --remote foobar.txt`

Comment: Could not bring this to work. Mac (HS) says: Unknown option argument: "--remote" On Windows a server definition is required, then it opens the normal additional window. Is it possible that there is no term driver for powershell and cmd on x64? In the 90s there where vi.com, which was a subset of vi. Maybe we need a port?